# DHT11 and Liquidcrystal setting cursor issue

Tags: lcd, atmega2560

```cpp
lcd_key = read_LCD_buttons();
float temp = dht.readTemperature();
delay(1000);
// lcd.setCursor(0,0);

if(temp < 0) {
    lcd.print(temp);  
}

if(temp >= 0.00 || temp <= 5.00) {
    lcd.setCursor(0,6);
    lcd.print(temp);
    delay(100);  
}
```

Here I got simple code about reading temperature from DHT sensor and lcd but when I raise or lower the DHT's temperature the lcd's cursor always printing my data from 0,0.

I want that when the temperature between 0-5 celcius it shall write data on 0,6 in lcd screen but this code not working.

Thank you for answers.

Comment: review the `setcutsor()` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling you may be using invalid coordinates.

`0, 6` means *Column 0, Row 6*, but most LCDs don't have 6 rows.  Instead I think you want `6, 0` for *Column 6, row 0*.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it because you use

```
if(temp >= 0.00 || temp <= 5.00){ // writes over 0 OR under 5 which will always be true for all values measured
```

and not

```
if(temp >= 0.00 && temp <= 5.00){   // writes over 0 AND under 5 which you want
```

Comment: the logic error in the OP's code causes temp to always print at (0,6)